# Date ranges: inclusive vs strict boundaries

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, datetime, user-interface

When allowing a user to select a date range, let's say:

> Show me entries from [**August 1**] to [**September 1**]

As a user, I would generally expect this to include the results for September 1. Especially when you consider that when I select the same date for both ends, I obviously mean "from start of day to end of day":

> Show me entries from [**September 1**] to [**September 1**]

As a programmer, I think of date boundaries as "zero-hour", i.e. "start-of-day"; logically, the entries for September 1 are actually *after* "2010-09-01 00:00:00" (hence outside of the range).

For example, in SQL the following condition would exclude everything:

```
SELECT * FROM entries
WHERE created_at >= DATE('2010-09-01') AND created_at <= DATE('2010-09-01')
```

Obviously, an adjustment needs to be made from the user input to the SQL to advance the end date by 24 hours.

However, that only applies to *timestamp* or *datetime* columns. When the column is a *date* then a direct comparison works and this adjustment should not be added.

In an MVC framework such as Rails, where do you handle the logic for this input mismatch before sending a query? If it's in the controller, it seems that relies too much on knowing the internal fields of the model (date vs. datetime), and if it's in the model, would a "find_in_date_range" method be understood as inclusive, or does that just invite off-by-day errors?

Finally, is my assumption correct for having the user interface represent inclusive ranges? Is this always the case or are there situations where a strict (exclusive) date boundary is more appropriate? For example, in my rake scripts I use the parameter `END_DATE=2010-09-01` to capture *up to* this date, which is inconsistent with the UI, but makes sense to me: where do you draw this line?

Comment: *Finally, is my assumption correct for having the user interface represent inclusive ranges?* -  Yes, "September 1st", for users, is a time range of a whole day, not a specific moment in time as it is for datetime columns.

Answer (score 7):

My Personal Bias:

Program it however you think the users will like it, but ALWAYS make the inclusive vs exclusive choice explicit in the GUI with labeling. Rather than saying

```
Between _____________ and ______________
```

I always label as

```
On or after _______________ but before _______________
```

or

```
On or after ______________ through ______________
```

(If you are writing software that a few users use every day and you can carefully train them, then they aren't going to be reading the GUI labels anyway, so don't bother.)